# design a restful API for book management system (JSON Data, Spring MVC, Restful API)

Tags: json, spring, rest, post, get

I am new to all the stuff I have posted below. I know basic Java programming. I have used base level soap stuff in the past. But here I do not understand what this Rest API is? How does it look? What does it deliver when its developed?

I would appreciate any help which can guide me where to start, what classes to create, what technologies to understand before I start this work. I really want to learn this stuff.

I want to build a RESTful API using Spring MVC

I have to build a book management system for library.

1)It must support JSON data format for the API.

2)Application Name should be “library” so that all endpoints will start with

3)http://x.x.x.x:8080/library.

4)Application server must be running on port 8080.

**1)Resource Model**

Books --->  Reviews
|
|
Authors

**2) Resource Details**

**Books**

---ISBN (Key) # You will generate this key.

---Title (Required field)

---Publication Date (Required field)

---Language (Optional field)

---Number of Pages (Optional field)

---Status {available, checked-out, in-queue, or lost} # default to ‘available’

**Authors**

---ID (Key) # You will generate this key.

---Name (Required field)

**Reviews**

---ID (Key) # You will generate this key.

---Rating (1-5 stars) (Required field)

---Comment (Required field)

****API's to build****
1) Root API -

○ Resource: GET - / (E.g http://x.y.z:8080/library/v1/)

○ Description: This is where the client can start the workflow of the system. Returns a list of links to start the workflow, which is to create new books.

Expected Response:

```
HTTP Code: 200
{
“links” : [
{ “rel”: “create-book”, “herf”: “/books”, “method”: “POST” }
]
}
```

2)Create Book API

○ Resource: POST - /books

○ Description: Add a new book along with the author information to the library.

Example Request: POST /books with the following payload in the request body.

```
{
"title" : "Programming Amazon EC2",
"publication-date" : "2/11/2011",
"language" : "eng",
"num-pages": 185,
"status" : "available",
"authors" : [
{ "name" : "Jurg Vliet" },
{"name" : "FlaviaPagenelli"} ]
}
```

Expected Response:

```
HTTP Code: 201

{
“links” : [
{ “rel”: “view-book”, “herf”: “/books/1”, “method”: “GET” },
{ “rel”: “update-book”, “herf”: “/books/1”, “method”: “PUT” },
{ “rel”: “delete-book”, “herf”: “/books/1”, “method”: “DELETE” },
{ “rel”: “create-review”, “herf”: “/books/1/reviews”, “method”: “POST” }
]
}
```

Similarly many more API's......

Thanking in advance, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a specific question about REST or spring, please ask it, but broad questions like this are not the right format for here.

Comment: Hey, Jeff

I know man that broad questions cannot be asked here. I just uploaded all this stuff here so that person trying to help me can get an idea what I am trying to understand.

Short answers pointing right directions will be appreciated.

Comment: Jyot, in the future you might want to use ServiceStack's RestHandler for your restful api infrastructure, https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

You can configure the port numbers at you application server(like jboss by default it is configured to 8080). And deploy the "library.war" in it. So that you can directly use ttp://x.x.x.x:8080/library

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/ will help you preparing JSON responses.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will look in the articles and get back if I have any doubts.